# SoapExtension won't execute

Tags: .net, web-services, soap-extension

I have a `SoapExtension` which, for now, only writes a log:

```
public class CatchInputParametersExtension : SoapExtension
{
    public override object GetInitializer(Type serviceType)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override object GetInitializer(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, SoapExtensionAttribute attribute)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public override void Initialize(object initializer)
    {
        //nothing to do
    }

    public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message)
    {
        Logger.Log("++++++++ Before Everything +++++++ " + message.ToString(), LogLevel.Info);

        switch (message.Stage)
        {
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize:
                Logger.Log("++++++++ Before Serialize +++++++ " + message.ToString(), LogLevel.Info);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize:
                Logger.Log("++++++++ After Serialize +++++++ " + message.ToString(), LogLevel.Info);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.BeforeDeserialize:
                Logger.Log("++++++++ Before Deserialize +++++++ " + message.ToString(), LogLevel.Info);
                break;
            case SoapMessageStage.AfterDeserialize:
                Logger.Log("++++++++ After Deserialize +++++++ " + message.ToString(), LogLevel.Info);
                break;
            default:
                throw new Exception("invalid stage");
        }

    }
}
```

I tried registering it with both `web.config` file

```
<webServices>
  <soapExtensionTypes>
    <add type="WebAdminServices.SoapExtensions.CatchInputParametersExtension,WebAdminServices" priority="1" group="Low"/>
  </soapExtensionTypes>
</webServices>
```

and `SoapExtensionAttribute`

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class CatchInputParametersAttribute : SoapExtensionAttribute
{

    private int priority;

    public override Type ExtensionType
    {
        get { return typeof(CatchInputParametersExtension); }
    }

    public override int Priority
    {
        get { return priority; }
        set { priority = value; }
    }

}
```

which is registered by

```
    [WebMethod(Description = "Test1")]
    [CatchInputParametersAttribute(Priority=1)]
    public string Test1(int a, int b, int c)
    {
        // do stuff

        return stuff;
    }
```

but none of them seems to work, the log file never shows those `++++++` lines. Any hints, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is a little bit silly. The `SoapExtension` is working fine, but I was calling the web method through the automatically generated `HTTP Post`, thinking that the `SoapExtension` was executing underneath. But it wasn't.

So for trigger its execution you need to call it through a client using a `SOAP` request directly. For that purpose I used [WebServiceStudio](http://webservicestudio.codeplex.com/), which analyzes a given `.wsdl` and lets you make `SOAP` requests.

More info: [Using SOAP Extensions in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164007.aspx).